# gpg-agent ssh-support throwing sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "(none)" from agent: agent refused

Tags: arch-linux, gnupg, systemd, gpg-agent

I am using Arch Linux and gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27. Trying to do a ssh-support with gpg, This i used along with git ssh public key authetication. For that  i created a pubic key from gpg.

When the socket activation happen and when i check the systemctl status for gpg-agent.

```
Mar 05 13:19:58 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15051]: using fd 3 for ssh socket (/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh)
Mar 05 13:19:58 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15051]: using fd 4 for extra socket (/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra)
Mar 05 13:19:58 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15051]: using fd 5 for browser socket (/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser)
Mar 05 13:19:58 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15051]: using fd 6 for std socket (/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent)
Mar 05 13:19:58 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15051]: listening on: std=6 extra=4 browser=5 ssh=3
Mar 05 13:19:58 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15053]: scdaemon[15053]: pcsc_establish_context failed: no service (0x8010001d)
Mar 05 13:20:17 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15053]: scdaemon[15053]: pcsc_establish_context failed: no service (0x8010001d)
Mar 05 13:20:18 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15051]: failed to unprotect the secret key: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Mar 05 13:20:18 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15051]: failed to read the secret key
Mar 05 13:20:18 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15051]: ssh sign request failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device <Pinentry>
```

And when i do git push i get below error

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "(none)" from agent: agent refused operation
remote: Public key authentication failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

***Working case***

The command i used is explain below.  The only way i can make it work is using below method, with a socket activation or systemd it is not working.

```
 gpg-agent  --enable-ssh-support --daemon
```

the above command produce an output shown below, Execute that output in next command.

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/gnupg/d.9e8e8c1bboxm43ocazxnxq5w/S.gpg-agent.ssh; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
```

After that if i tried to do git push, I am able to get prompt and it is working.

***How i was able to produce same error of systemd in above method. Steps explain below***

In the same command prompt, when i do git push , the prompt I cancel , I am getting same error , what i was getting in systemd

sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "(none)" from agent: agent refused operation
remote: Public key authentication failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

***All the setup and error explain below using SYSTEMD***

Not getting what exactly i am missing. I gone through blog. and tried troubleshoot, not getting exactly what i am missing

Please find my setup and troubleshooting method i used

I use xdg directory specification for folder structures.

using the environment.d folder in ~/.config to load all the environment variables for my systemd process.

Attaching the environment variables below.

```
#GPG_TTY=$(tty)
GPG_TTY=/dev/pts/0
TERM=linux
#PATH="$(/usr/bin/du -L --exclude=.idea --exclude=archive --exclude=__pycache__ $HOME/.local/bin/vbin| /usr/bin/cut -f2 | /usr/bin/tr '\n' ':')$PATH"
PATH="$HOME/.local/bin/vbin/bspwm:/$HOME/.local/bin/vbin:$PATH"
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/share/npm/bin:$HOME/.local/bin/net.downloadhelper.coapp-1.3.0/bin:$HOME/.local/bin

# default programs:
EDITOR="emsc"
VISUAL="${EDITOR}"
TERMINAL="st"
BROWSER="firefox"
FILE="lf"
STATUSBAR="polybar"

#Other program settings
VCONFIG=${HOME}/.config/vconfig
VBIN=${HOME}/.local/bin/vbin
SUDO_ASKPASS=${VBIN}/dmenupass
ORGPATH=${HOME}/Org

#XDG CONFIG MOVEMENTS

XDG_CONFIG_HOME=${HOME}/.config
XDG_DATA_HOME=${HOME}/.local/share
XDG_CACHE_HOME=${HOME}/.cache

GNUPGHOME=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/gnupg
IPYTHONDIR=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/jupyter
JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/jupyter
ZDOTDIR=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/.config/zsh
NPM_CONFIG_USERCONFIG=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/npm/config
LESSKEY=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/less/lesskey
GTK2_RC_FILES=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/java
ANDROID_SDK_HOME=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/android
ADB_VENDOR_KEY=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/android

WINEPREFIX=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/wineprefixes/default
HISTFILE=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/zsh/history
_Z_DATA=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/.z
GOPATH=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/go
GNUPGHOME=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/gnupg
PASSWORD_STORE_DIR=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/pass
VSCODE_PORTABLE=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/vscode
ANDROID_AVD_HOME=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/android
ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/android

NUGET_PACKAGES=${XDG_CACHE_HOME}/NuGetPackages
PYLINTHOME=${XDG_CACHE_HOME}/pylint
LESSHISTFILE=${XDG_CACHE_HOME}/less/history
CUDA_CACHE_PATH=${XDG_CACHE_HOME}/nv

SSH_AUTH_SOCK="${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh"


CM_SELECTIONS="clipboard"
CM_DEBUG=0
CM_OUTPUT_CLIP=0
CM_MAX_CLIPS=100
CM_LAUNCHER="rofi"
ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT=8080

LF_ICONS="\
di=:\
fi=:\
ln=:\
or=:\
ex=:\
*.c=:\
*.cc=:\
*.clj=:\
*.coffee=:\
*.cpp=:\
*.css=:\
*.d=:\
*.dart=:\
*.erl=:\
*.exs=:\
*.fs=:\
*.go=:\
*.h=:\
*.hh=:\
*.hpp=:\
*.hs=:\
*.html=:\
*.java=:\
*.jl=:\
*.js=:\
*.json=:\
*.lua=:\
*.md=:\
*.php=:\
*.pl=:\
*.pro=:\
*.py=:\
*.rb=:\
*.rs=:\
*.scala=:\
*.ts=:\
*.vim=:\
*.cmd=:\
*.ps1=:\
*.sh=:\
*.bash=:\
*.zsh=:\
*.fish=:\
*.tar=:\
*.tgz=:\
*.arc=:\
*.arj=:\
*.taz=:\
*.lha=:\
*.lz4=:\
*.lzh=:\
*.lzma=:\
*.tlz=:\
*.txz=:\
*.tzo=:\
*.t7z=:\
*.zip=:\
*.z=:\
*.dz=:\
*.gz=:\
*.lrz=:\
*.lz=:\
*.lzo=:\
*.xz=:\
*.zst=:\
*.tzst=:\
*.bz2=:\
*.bz=:\
*.tbz=:\
*.tbz2=:\
*.tz=:\
*.deb=:\
*.rpm=:\
*.jar=:\
*.war=:\
*.ear=:\
*.sar=:\
*.rar=:\
*.alz=:\
*.ace=:\
*.zoo=:\
*.cpio=:\
*.7z=:\
*.rz=:\
*.cab=:\
*.wim=:\
*.swm=:\
*.dwm=:\
*.esd=:\
*.jpg=:\
*.jpeg=:\
*.mjpg=:\
*.mjpeg=:\
*.gif=:\
*.bmp=:\
*.pbm=:\
*.pgm=:\
*.ppm=:\
*.tga=:\
*.xbm=:\
*.xpm=:\
*.tif=:\
*.tiff=:\
*.png=:\
*.svg=:\
*.svgz=:\
*.mng=:\
*.pcx=:\
*.mov=:\
*.mpg=:\
*.mpeg=:\
*.m2v=:\
*.mkv=:\
*.webm=:\
*.ogm=:\
*.mp4=:\
*.m4v=:\
*.mp4v=:\
*.vob=:\
*.qt=:\
*.nuv=:\
*.wmv=:\
*.asf=:\
*.rm=:\
*.rmvb=:\
*.flc=:\
*.avi=:\
*.fli=:\
*.flv=:\
*.gl=:\
*.dl=:\
*.xcf=:\
*.xwd=:\
*.yuv=:\
*.cgm=:\
*.emf=:\
*.ogv=:\
*.ogx=:\
*.aac=:\
*.au=:\
*.flac=:\
*.m4a=:\
*.mid=:\
*.midi=:\
*.mka=:\
*.mp3=:\
*.mpc=:\
*.ogg=:\
*.ra=:\
*.wav=:\
*.oga=:\
*.opus=:\
*.spx=:\
*.xspf=:\
*.pdf=:\
*.nix=:\
"
```

In the above environment setting , i set the    GNUPGHOME=${XDG_DATA_HOME}/gnupg

permision on my GNUPGHOME

```
total 84K

drwx------ 2 vipin vipin 4.0K Nov  8 18:50 openpgp-revocs.d
drwx------ 2 vipin vipin 4.0K Mar  4 00:22 private-keys-v1.d
-rw------- 1 vipin vipin  105 Mar  5 10:10 gpg-agent.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 vipin vipin  16K Mar  4 00:23 pubring.kbx
-rw-r--r-- 1 vipin vipin   41 Mar  4 00:41 sshcontrol
-rw-r--r-- 1 vipin vipin  48K Mar  4 00:23 tofu.db
-rw------- 1 vipin vipin 1.3K Nov  8 18:50 trustdb.gpg
```

The /home/vipin/.local/share/gnupg/gpg-agent.conf file contain below information.

```
default-cache-ttl 240
enable-ssh-support
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-gtk-2
pinentry-mode loopback
```

Pinentry program files and permission

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  122 Nov 13  2019 /usr/bin/pinentry
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  71K Nov 13  2019 /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  63K Nov 13  2019 /usr/bin/pinentry-emacs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  79K Nov 13  2019 /usr/bin/pinentry-gnome3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  91K Nov 13  2019 /usr/bin/pinentry-gtk-2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 127K Nov 13  2019 /usr/bin/pinentry-qt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  67K Nov 13  2019 /usr/bin/pinentry-tty
```

SSH socket, added in the environment variable.

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK="${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh"
```

System service at /home/vipin/.local/share/systemd/user/ and using **socket activation to start  gpg-agent.service**

```
gpg-agent-browser.socket  
gpg-agent.socket
gpg-agent-extra.socket    
gpg-agent-ssh.socket
gpg-agent.service
```

gpg-agent.service

```
[Unit]
Description=GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache
Documentation=man:gpg-agent(1)
Requires=gpg-agent.socket

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gpg-agent --supervised --enable-ssh-support
ExecReload=/usr/bin/gpgconf --reload gpg-agent
```

gpg-agent.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache
Documentation=man:gpg-agent(1)

[Socket]
ListenStream=%t/gnupg/S.gpg-agent
FileDescriptorName=std
SocketMode=0600
DirectoryMode=0700

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

gpg-agent-ssh.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation)
Documentation=man:gpg-agent(1) man:ssh-add(1) man:ssh-agent(1) man:ssh(1)

[Socket]
ListenStream=%t/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
FileDescriptorName=ssh
Service=gpg-agent.service
SocketMode=0600
DirectoryMode=0700

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

gpg-agent-extra.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted)
Documentation=man:gpg-agent(1)

[Socket]
ListenStream=%t/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
FileDescriptorName=extra
Service=gpg-agent.service
SocketMode=0600
DirectoryMode=0700

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

gpg-agent-browser.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers)
Documentation=man:gpg-agent(1)

[Socket]
ListenStream=%t/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser
FileDescriptorName=browser
Service=gpg-agent.service
SocketMode=0600
DirectoryMode=0700

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

After configuring above setting i did a new sub-key in gpg for authentication.

Then executed the command and created  sshcontrol at /home/vipin/.local/share/gnupg/ copied only the Keygrip  for authentication.

```
gpg --list-keys --with-keygrip
```

when execute systemctl --user status gpg-agent i can see some error getting trigger

```
   Mar 05 13:19:58 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15051]: using fd 3 for ssh socket (/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh)
Mar 05 13:19:58 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15051]: using fd 4 for extra socket (/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra)
Mar 05 13:19:58 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15051]: using fd 5 for browser socket (/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser)
Mar 05 13:19:58 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15051]: using fd 6 for std socket (/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent)
Mar 05 13:19:58 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15051]: listening on: std=6 extra=4 browser=5 ssh=3
Mar 05 13:19:58 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15053]: scdaemon[15053]: pcsc_establish_context failed: no service (0x8010001d)
Mar 05 13:20:17 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15053]: scdaemon[15053]: pcsc_establish_context failed: no service (0x8010001d)
Mar 05 13:20:18 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15051]: failed to unprotect the secret key: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Mar 05 13:20:18 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15051]: failed to read the secret key
Mar 05 13:20:18 vipin-pc gpg-agent[15051]: ssh sign request failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device <Pinentry>
```

But when I tried to do ssh-add -l . I can see connection

4096 SHA256: (none) (RSA)                                                                        /0.0s

I also did ps -eaf |grep  gpg-agent I can see gpg-agent using socket activation.

```
vipin      12147     573  0 12:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/gpg-agent --supervised --enable-ssh-support
```

When I tried to gpg --export-ssh-key VipinBalakrishnan. I am able to see the public key exported.

I used above public key in azuredev apps. So that I can used SSH-
key to authenticate.

After configuring everything. When i tried to

```
git push

Getting below error
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "(none)" from agent: agent refused operation
remote: Public key authentication failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I gone through the Arch  wiki link https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG

I gone through the troubleshoot section. But not getting any clue.
Some blog told it is not identify the tty. For that i executed

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye >/dev/null
```

**Output**

```
gpg-connect-agent: no running gpg-agent - starting '/usr/bin/gpg-agent'
gpg-connect-agent: waiting for the agent to come up ... (5s)
gpg-connect-agent: connection to agent established
```

But the above command create different process of gpg-agent without supervised mode. It is pursing daemon. And the socket will be different.
When i do
ps -eaf |grep  gpg-agent I can see it is in daemon mode.

```
vipin      13327       1  0 12:52 ?        00:00:00 gpg-agent --homedir /home/vipin/.local/share/gnupg --use-standard-socket --daemon
```

Comment: At last i got the solution after a lot of search. I just added display :0 at /home/vipin/.local/share/gnupg/gpg-agent.conf

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The gpg-agent in some cases won't run the pinentry program and will just refuse to sign the key.
After running `gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye >/dev/null` and testing an SSH connection the thing asked for the passphrase again and the connection succeeded.
Who knows what the bug is.

Comment: Mongrelion, my issue was i was not getting password prompt? Is it same for you too?

Comment: yes, exactly the same issue!